# Generate ER diagrams from Oracle db (with missing foreign keys)

Tags: database, oracle

Is there any software that can automatically generate the ER diagram from the Oracle database?

My problem is that the db has some "noise" in the design process that it missed out some mandatory foreign keys. Furthermore, the size of db is quite large, and one cannot simply go through every table to manually check.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: "one cannot simply go through every table to manually check" ... why not? not enough time, or no direct access to the database?

Comment: the number of tables is quite large, my friend. So I would say it's time-consuming :)

Comment: Life is like that sometimes :) but kudos for at least trying to find a quicker solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if there are "missing" mandatry foreign keys, then, technically, those foreign keys are not mandatory, and not missing. But I feel your pain.

Probably, as a started, I'd search for tables that share column names and whose column name appears in the primary key columns for the tables:

```
select 
  a.table_name,
  b.table_name,
  a.column_name
from
      all_tab_columns   a 
join  all_tab_columns   b on a.table_name != b.table_name and
                             a.column_name = b.column_name
join  all_tables        u on b.table_name  = u.table_name   -- Exlude Views!
join  all_constraints   p on a.table_name  = p.table_name and
                             p.constraint_type = 'P'
join  all_cons_columns  c on p.constraint_name = c.constraint_name and
                             c.column_name = a.column_name
```